# Using 2 Cursors from 2 different tables to populate an ExpandableListView with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite

Lets say I have two tables: One is "box sizes", the other is "fruits". Every fruit has a box size that it is packaged in. I only want 3 categories of box sizes, and within those I may have 4-5 fruits. So my groups would come from the "box size table" and children from the "fruits" table.

I have tried overriding the getChildrenCursor to no avail. It says the column from "fruits" does not exist, because I assumed it uses one cursor.

How would I get around this?

```
cU=dB.fetchTypes(cId);
        SimpleCursorTreeAdapter mAdapter = new     SimpleCursorTreeAdapter(this,
                cU, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                new String[] { SQLAdapter.KEY_BOXNAME }, new int[] {R.id.exp_group_text1},
                R.layout.exprow_group, R.layout.exprow_child, new String[] { SQLAdapter.KEY_FRUITNAME},
                new int[] { R.id.exp_child_text1 }) {

            //we return a new cursor representing fruit for each box selected
            @Override
            protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
                secondCu = dB.fetchFruitesOfBox(new Long(groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(SQLAdapter.KEY_BOXID))));
                secondCu.moveToFirst();
                return secondCu;
            }
        };
        expView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Do you mind posting some code with what you tried? Also I think you are referring to the `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` and not `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: You should certainly be able to do it.  Please post your code so we can see where you might have gone astray.

Comment: ok, posted code. Sorry about being unclear as well ( I did mean SimpleCursorTreeAdapter).

Comment: Does this exception appear only in the `getChildrenCursor` method or it appears anywhere you use the fruits table?

Comment: Could you post your `fetchFruitesOfBox` method? and I don't believe that `new Long` bit in there is helping you at all...